# Mouse out is not working with all directions

Tags: jquery, html, mouseover, mouseout

**HTML**

```
<!--DASHBOARD-->
   <li class="always_show">
      <span class="menu_large_item" style="display: none;">
          <a href="/xyz/dashboard">
             <div class="ribbon-body-prof-menu">Dashboard</div>
          </a>
      </span>
      <a class="menu_small_item" href="/dashboard"> V </a>
    </li>
 <!--DASHBOARD-->


<!--PROFILE -->
    <li class="always_show" id="profile_menu_item">  
        <span class="menu_large_item" style="display: none;">
            <a href="/xyz/profile/iprofile/id/3">
                <div class="ribbon-body-prof-menu"> Profile</div>
            </a>
 <!--PROFILE -->
        </span>
        <a class="menu_small_item" class="selected" href="/profile/iprofile/id/3">

<!-- <img src="http://localhost/xyz/public/images/icon-industries.png" alt="Profile" title="Profile" width="12" height="15"> -->
                    N
        </a>
     </li>
```

Now I want that when i hover over the `menu_small_item`, the `menu_large_item` part shows and when I mouse out from `menu_small_item`, then `menu_large_item` part hides. Same is happening but in case of last item in my html, when I take my mouse out from downwards nothing happens.

**jQuery:**

```
    $('li.always_show, a.menu_small_item').mouseover(function(){
        $(this).siblings('li.always_show span.menu_large_item').show();
    $(this).siblings('span').children('a').children('div.ribbon-body-prof-menu').show();
});
$('li.always_show span.menu_large_item, .ribbon-body-prof-menu').mouseout(function(){
    $(this).hide();
    $('li.always_show span.menu_large_item').hide();
    $('div.ribbon-body-prof-menu').css('display','none');       
});
```

I have implemented the same on

https://jsfiddle.net/shilpi_jas/nh1n4pcv/
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It could be that although you're visually moving out of it, you're actually still on it because it's higher than you see. Have you tried inspecting the code ? It's actually hard to say without seeing a CSS or, better, a jsFiddle reproducing the issue, so I think you should build one...

Comment: @Bartdude  when I put alert on mouseout it works where as hiding of element not working. Let me make my code live then i will give you link to inspect.

Comment: @Bartdude Go to http://phpdemo.seasiainfotech.com:9040/ilook/dev credentials :-  email:hkaur5@seasiainfotech.com, password: mind@123 and then go to http://phpdemo.seasiainfotech.com:9040/ilook/dev/profile/my-iprofile. check the middle menu to inspect.

Comment: @Simer Did you try my solution?

Comment: @Bartdude In middle bar, hover on 'P' and move mouse down, you will find that ribbon does not hide.

Comment: Please create a narrowed down fiddle with your code. Live links are soon to become obsolete and won't be helpful to future SO users. In addition, you might even identify the root cause of your problem when narrowing it down.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/shilpi_jas/nh1n4pcv/ . Please refer this fiddle.

Comment: @johnR : yes I did. FadeOut is working. Thanks. But I dont want that effect, I want to use hide and show functions. But thanks for your contribution. :)

Comment: @bartdude jsfiddle.net/shilpi_jas/nh1n4pcv . Please refer this fiddle.

Comment: Just tried the fiddle on IE and Chrome and despite a small display issue which doesn't seem related to the problem, it works when leaving the item from all directions...

Comment: @Bartdude 'ribbon-body-prof-menu' part does not disappear when i move my mouse out in downward direction. I am talking about last element 'P'.

Comment: cfr my answer using a different approach. Please note that reading/updating your fiddle would be much easier if you really narrowed it down. I mean, we don't need all these HTML comments nor the 6k lines of CSS...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the feeling the complicated HTML+CSS structure (with use of floats and so on) somehow is causing this. If you inspect your code with developer tools, you can see the overlay when you hover each element composing your HTML is most of the time not at the right place. I then thought about a no-js solution which from where I see it is very similar to your functionality, with a much simpler HTML... and no javascript to fail. Here's my proposition that you can hopefully fit into your application, or at least take inspiration from :

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a class="menu_small_item" href="#">A</a>
        <a class="menu_large_item" href="#">Lorem</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="menu_small_item" href="#">B</a>
        <a class="menu_large_item" href="#">Ipsum</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="menu_small_item" href="#">C</a>
        <a class="menu_large_item" href="#">Dolor</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="menu_small_item" href="#">D</a>
        <a class="menu_large_item" href="#">Sit</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="menu_small_item" href="#">E</a>
        <a class="menu_large_item" href="#">Amet</a>
    </li>
<ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul {list-style-type:none;width:100px;}
li {margin-bottom:15px;cursor:pointer;}
li a {display:block;width:85px;padding:5px;text-decoration: none;}
.menu_small_item { color: #b084e9;}
.menu_large_item { display: none;color: #fff;background: #4D356F;box-sizing: border-box;}
li:hover > .menu_small_item {display:none;}
li:hover > .menu_large_item {display:block;}
```

And [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0jLawm6e/) for demo

Answer (score 1):

Use `fadeTo` method of jQuery instead of using `show` and `hide` method. Because `mouseout` event will not trigger for the hidden elements.

But this `fadeTo` method will changes the opacity of the element for showing and hiding it and hence all mouse events will trigger in this scenario.

Please refer this [doc](https://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/)

Use `fadeTo(1, 1)` instead of `show()` and `fadeTo(1, 0)` instead of `hide()`